# Android Wear 2.0 emulator freezes

Tags: android-wear-2.0

I've seen a problem where **Instant Run** causes the emulator to freeze. This happens especially when I have a high frame rate, let's say 24 or 30.

The expected behavior would be for my `CanvasWatchFaceService` to be killed and restarted but instead, it gets into a frozen state where all I can do is to restart the emulator because not even the power button would work.

This is a logcat of the event:

```
11-15 11:40:59.199  2992  2992 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-15 11:40:59.200  2992  2992 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-15 11:40:59.201  2992  2992 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
11-15 11:40:59.228  2992  2992 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-15 11:40:59.231  2992  2992 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-15 11:40:59.246  2992  2992 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-15 11:40:59.246  2992  2992 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-15 11:40:59.247  2992  2992 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-15 11:40:59.254  2992  2992 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-15 11:40:59.266  2992  2992 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
11-15 11:40:59.266  2992  2992 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {7c76d81} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {7c76d81} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:643)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:612)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:582)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:338)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:57)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at com.android.internal.os.IResultReceiver$Stub.onTransact(IResultReceiver.java:58)
11-15 11:40:59.267  2992  3000 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
11-15 11:40:59.403  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received connection from IDE: spawning connection thread
11-15 11:40:59.406  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received Ping message from the IDE; returned active = false
11-15 11:40:59.408  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received EOF from the IDE
11-15 11:40:59.420  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received connection from IDE: spawning connection thread
11-15 11:40:59.427  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received Ping message from the IDE; returned active = false
11-15 11:40:59.429  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received EOF from the IDE
11-15 11:40:59.606  3011  3011 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-15 11:40:59.607  3011  3011 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-15 11:40:59.607  3011  3011 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
11-15 11:40:59.631  3011  3011 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-15 11:40:59.634  3011  3011 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-15 11:40:59.651  3011  3011 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-15 11:40:59.651  3011  3011 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-15 11:40:59.652  3011  3011 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-15 11:40:59.661  3011  3011 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {7c76d81} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {7c76d81} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:643)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:612)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:582)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:338)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:57)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at com.android.internal.os.IResultReceiver$Stub.onTransact(IResultReceiver.java:58)
11-15 11:40:59.672  3011  3019 W MessageQueue:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
11-15 11:40:59.673  3011  3011 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
11-15 11:40:59.673  3011  3011 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
11-15 11:41:00.947  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received connection from IDE: spawning connection thread
11-15 11:41:00.951  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received Ping message from the IDE; returned active = false
11-15 11:41:00.954  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received EOF from the IDE
11-15 11:41:00.968  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received connection from IDE: spawning connection thread
11-15 11:41:00.973  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Receiving 1 changes
11-15 11:41:00.977  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received dex shard /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex
11-15 11:41:00.978  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Finished loading changes; update mode =3
11-15 11:41:00.982  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Waiting for app to be killed and restarted by the IDE...
11-15 11:41:00.982  2942  2964 V InstantRun: Received EOF from the IDE
11-15 11:41:01.162  3023  3023 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-15 11:41:01.163  3023  3023 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-15 11:41:01.163  3023  3023 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
11-15 11:41:01.186  3023  3023 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-15 11:41:01.189  3023  3023 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-15 11:41:01.207  3023  3023 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-15 11:41:01.207  3023  3023 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-15 11:41:01.208  3026  3026 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-15 11:41:01.208  3023  3023 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-15 11:41:01.210  3026  3026 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-15 11:41:01.210  3026  3026 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
11-15 11:41:01.218  3023  3023 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
11-15 11:41:01.221  3023  3023 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-15 11:41:01.224  3023  3034 W art     : Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder:3023_1
11-15 11:41:01.224  3023  3034 I AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder:3023_1' failed
11-15 11:41:01.249  3026  3026 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-15 11:41:01.257  3026  3026 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-15 11:41:01.280  3026  3026 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-15 11:41:01.280  3026  3026 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-15 11:41:01.281  3026  3026 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-15 11:41:01.292  3026  3026 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-15 11:41:01.294  1540  2084 I ActivityManager: Force stopping PACKAGE_NAME appid=10040 user=0: from pid 3026
11-15 11:41:01.294  1540  2084 I ActivityManager: Killing 2942:PACKAGE_NAME/u0a40 (adj 100): stop PACKAGE_NAME
11-15 11:41:01.294  1540  2084 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 2942
11-15 11:41:01.295  1540  2084 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service PACKAGE_NAME/com.breel.mgi.metronome.MetronomeWatchFace in 1000ms
11-15 11:41:01.295  1540  2084 I ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{47860eb u0 PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.MetronomeWatchFace}
11-15 11:41:01.296  3026  3026 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-15 11:41:01.296  1540  1540 W WallpaperManagerService: Wallpaper service gone: ComponentInfo{PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.MetronomeWatchFace}
11-15 11:41:01.299  1540  1581 W InputDispatcher: channel 'db461bf com.breel.mgi.metronome.MetronomeWatchFace (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-15 11:41:01.299  1540  1581 E InputDispatcher: channel 'db461bf com.breel.mgi.metronome.MetronomeWatchFace (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-15 11:41:01.300  1540  2018 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{db461bf u0 com.breel.mgi.metronome.MetronomeWatchFace}
11-15 11:41:01.300  1540  2018 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'db461bf com.breel.mgi.metronome.MetronomeWatchFace (server)'
11-15 11:41:01.304  1540  1553 W WallpaperManagerService: Wallpaper uninstalled, removing: ComponentInfo{PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.MetronomeWatchFace}
11-15 11:41:01.305  1709  1709 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
11-15 11:41:18.406  1540  1581 I InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{4cbc0b3 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home2.activity.HomeActivity2}.  It has been 5007.8ms since event, 5007.3ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 16.  Wait queue head age: 5637.2ms.
11-15 11:41:51.376  1540  1683 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1540 SIG: 3
11-15 11:41:51.376  1540  1543 I art     : Thread[2,tid=1543,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa8588000,peer=0x12c010d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:41:51.376  1540  1543 I art     :
11-15 11:41:51.456  1540  1543 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:41:51.458  1214  1214 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1258 uid=1000 gid=1003 tid=1258
11-15 11:42:01.460  1214  1214 E         : debuggerd: worker process 3048 timed out
11-15 11:42:01.461  1214  1214 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1258
11-15 11:42:01.461  1214  1214 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1279 uid=1041 gid=1005 tid=1279
11-15 11:42:01.461  1214  1214 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
11-15 11:42:01.461  1214  1214 W         : debuggerd: pid 0 received signal 6
11-15 11:42:01.462  1214  1214 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1279
11-15 11:42:01.473  3052  3052 I         : debuggerd: starting
11-15 11:42:02.327  2167  2976 I DeviceStateChecker: screenOn: true, isCharging: true
11-15 11:42:10.011  1540  1554 W BroadcastQueue: Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{53f311c u-1 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@49e38b, started 10009ms ago
11-15 11:42:10.011  1540  1554 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{9020881 u0 ReceiverList{b4c6c68 1935 com.google.android.wearable.app/10005/u0 remote:49e38b}}
11-15 11:42:10.018  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1935 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:10.018  1935  1942 I art     : Thread[3,tid=1942,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c264c0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:10.018  1935  1942 I art     :
11-15 11:42:10.047  1935  1942 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:10.047  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1540 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:10.047  1540  1543 I art     : Thread[2,tid=1543,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa8588000,peer=0x12c010d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:10.047  1540  1543 I art     :
11-15 11:42:10.108  1540  1543 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:10.108  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1709 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:10.108  1709  1715 I art     : Thread[3,tid=1715,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c008b0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:10.108  1709  1715 I art     :
11-15 11:42:10.134  1709  1715 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:10.135  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1695 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:10.135  1695  1699 I art     : Thread[3,tid=1699,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c00670,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:10.135  1695  1699 I art     :
11-15 11:42:10.145  1695  1699 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:10.146  3052  3052 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1258 uid=1000 gid=1003 tid=1258
11-15 11:42:20.150  3052  3052 E         : debuggerd: worker process 3054 timed out
11-15 11:42:20.151  3052  3052 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1258
11-15 11:42:20.152  3052  3052 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1279 uid=1041 gid=1005 tid=1279
11-15 11:42:20.152  3052  3052 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
11-15 11:42:20.152  3052  3052 W         : debuggerd: pid 0 received signal 6
11-15 11:42:20.153  3052  3052 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1279
11-15 11:42:20.166  3058  3058 I         : debuggerd: starting
11-15 11:42:20.728  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1959 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:20.729  1959  1965 I art     : Thread[3,tid=1965,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c26790,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:20.729  1959  1965 I art     :
11-15 11:42:20.762  1959  1965 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:20.763  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 2114 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:20.763  2114  2120 I art     : Thread[3,tid=2120,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c2f700,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:20.763  2114  2120 I art     :
11-15 11:42:20.777  2114  2120 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:20.777  1540  1554 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 2167 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:20.777  2167  2173 I art     : Thread[3,tid=2173,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c2f940,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:20.777  2167  2173 I art     :
11-15 11:42:20.795  2167  2173 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.google.android.wearable.app
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: PID: 1935
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: Load: 1.56 / 0.61 / 0.26
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 0ms to 10784ms later (2016-11-15 11:42:10.011 to 2016-11-15 11:42:20.796):
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   100% 1258/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 100% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   6.3% 1540/system_server: 1.6% user + 4.6% kernel / faults: 496 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   2.9% 1264/adbd: 0% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 197 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   2.4% 2114/com.google.android.wearable.ambient: 1.2% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 556 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.6% 1279/audioserver: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.4% 1290/rild: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.4% 2167/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 604 minor 1 major
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0.3% 1959/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 606 minor 3 major
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 1709/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 573 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0.1% 1935/com.google.android.wearable.app: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 549 minor 2 major
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0% 1206/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   0% 1695/com.google.android.clockwork.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 571 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:  +0% 3058/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:  +0% 3059/debuggerd:signaller: 0% user + 0% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: 27% TOTAL: 0.3% user + 27% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 10198ms to 10707ms later (2016-11-15 11:42:20.210 to 2016-11-15 11:42:20.719):
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   100% 1258/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 100% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     100% 1258/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 100% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   3.9% 1540/system_server: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 2 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     3.9% 1571/SensorService: 0% user + 3.9% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.9% 1554/ActivityManager: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   3.7% 1959/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 79 minor
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 1977/HeapTaskDaemon: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.8% 1264/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 1265/qemu socket: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 1267/<-host-9: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.8% 1290/rild: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 1536/rild: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.8% 2114/com.google.android.wearable.ambient: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 2114/earable.ambient: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 2153/GestureDetectio: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:   1.8% 2167/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager:     1.8% 2225/User-Facing Sha: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
11-15 11:42:20.801  1540  1554 E ActivityManager: 27% TOTAL: 0% user + 27% kernel
11-15 11:42:31.465  1540  1683 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1540 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:31.465  1540  1543 I art     : Thread[2,tid=1543,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa8588000,peer=0x12c010d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:31.465  1540  1543 I art     :
11-15 11:42:31.533  1540  1543 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:31.533  1540  1683 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 1709 SIG: 3
11-15 11:42:31.533  1709  1715 I art     : Thread[3,tid=1715,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5c04e00,peer=0x12c008b0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
11-15 11:42:31.533  1709  1715 I art     :
11-15 11:42:31.557  1709  1715 I art     : Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-15 11:42:31.557  3058  3058 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1258 uid=1000 gid=1003 tid=1258
11-15 11:42:41.560  3058  3058 E         : debuggerd: worker process 3061 timed out
11-15 11:42:41.560  3058  3058 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1258
11-15 11:42:41.561  3058  3058 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1279 uid=1041 gid=1005 tid=1279
11-15 11:42:41.561  3058  3058 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
11-15 11:42:41.561  3058  3058 W         : debuggerd: pid 0 received signal 6
11-15 11:42:41.562  3058  3058 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 1279
11-15 11:42:41.576  3065  3065 I         : debuggerd: starting
11-15 11:42:43.566  1540  1683 I Watchdog_N: dumpKernelStacks
```

[And this is the output of **/data/anr/traces.txt**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_fjmg0virqMm5iRms3MjlYS0k/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks!